# HTML version of ● sign?

Tags: html

What's the HTML version of ● sign (e.g. `&nbsp;`)?

Comment: @Close-voter, how is this *not a real question*: it's *quite easy* to tell what is being asked here. This question *is not* ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and can *certainly* be reasonably answered in its current form... O.o

Comment: @David Thomas - In this instance if you look at the OP's questions, you *might* detect a pattern forming. :-)

Comment: That said, I have to agree with @David Thomas - this is still a perfectly valid question. The OP just needs to be educated - closing this question without reason won't help.

Comment: @middaparka, I did see the pattern (I caught his question regarding beta earlier this morning); but 'not a real question' isn't a pseudonym for 'obnoxious by means of not doing *any* research at all to answer his own question.'

Comment: Btw. what you want is the *HTML entity* for ●.

Comment: @David Thomas I totally agree. (I've not voted to close.) Also made a comment to that effect prior to your comment. I instead attempted to cover things within my answer. (My "pattern forming" comment was misleading in this respect - my bad.) :-)

Comment: @middaparka, I saw your new comment just after I added my response to your first...I chose to leave my own comment as-is because I think it's a valid continuation of my own first comment; albeit it probably ceases to be relevant as an `@` comment any longer.

Comment: @urRetard, **please don't remove your questions just because they've been 'resolved', that's *not* what Stack Overflow is for.**

Comment: @urR you really better learn how to ask a question here if you want help. Fighting the members here will surely do the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 'bullet character'?

```
&#8226;
```

Comment: haha, can be, but it doesn't change the fast that

Answer (score 13):

**Please don't keep asking "What's the HTML version of XXX?" questions.**

Use a resource like http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/named-character-references.html that contains *all* the available symbols.

Comment: As a sideread, http://w3fools.com

Comment: @The MYYN - Irritatingly the "official" [W3C version](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) is about as useful as a chocolate fireguard. That said, if you can find a better resource I'll happily update. :-)

Comment: @urRetard - Not at all. It'll just be faster *for you* if you have a good resource to look at rather than having to ask a question every time.

Comment: @middaparka - http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/named-character-references.html#named-character-references

Comment: @Alohci - Cheers - I've updated my answer based on this. :-)

Answer (score 9):

`&bull;` or `&#x2022;` or `&#8226;` will do it as they all reference the same character.

- `&bull;` - The HTML Character reference. Gets replaced with the equivalent character entity
- `&#x2022;` - The HEX character entity
- `&#8226;` - The decimal character entity

There is more information on wikipedia - [Bullet (typography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_%28typography%29).

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
&middot;
```

or

```
&#183;
```

http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html